# How to set cookie version (0 or 1) used by java servlets?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, cookies

I'm looking for a way to configure my servlet to use cookie version 0, which supposedly disallows equals character (=) in cookies, plus other non URL-safe characters.

I have one server with ServletExec where the equals character is automatically discarded (it's using cookie version 0?). I have 2 other servers with ServletExec and Tomcat where the equals character isn't discarded (apparently they're using cookie version 1?).  I have no idea why they're behaving differently.

So I just need help locating the servlet configuration that sets the cookie version, or enables/disables the discarding of equals character in my cookies. TIA!

Answer (score 5):

I would say it is related to Tomcat configuration rather than servlet one.

By default Tomcat tries to parse your cookie value and basing on that value tries to 'guess' cookie version. In more details if it finds some version1-specific characters it will set cookie version to 1 automatically.
I.e. even if in your servlet you set cookie value to 0, Tomcat will overwrite it to 1 during response rendering.

To avoid such behaviour you can set
**org.apache.tomcat.util.http.CookieSupport.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0**
property to **true**.

This property is taken by Tomcat from system properties, i.e. setting this property value to true can be done using setting system property, updating catalina.properties or any other suitable way.

For complete details see 
**appendCookieValue** method in 
**org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie**
class

PS there is also a **ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE** setting in **CookieSupport** class which might be helpful in your case.